# Как хранить данные в БД?

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше распределить данные погоды по таблицам. Есть погода на сегодня, она делиться на 4 части: Ночь, Утро, День, Вечер. Вопрос заключается в следующем: Лучше создать отдельные таблицы для каждого времени суток или в одной таблице для одного дня добавить 4 строки с временами суток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще конечно, 2ой вариант. Одна таблица, в которой хранятся дни и данные о погоде с пометкой за какую часть дня эта погода. 
Это нормальная практика, да и выборки будет проще делать.